# simple 8086 compare instruction problem

Tags: assembly, x86-16, cmp

recently i have a 8086 assembly homework to finish,  i try to use the CMP instruction , but can't get it right.here is the code:

```
MOV AL, 88h
   CMP AL, 24h
   JL  exit
label:
   mov al,4h
exit:
   RET
```

when i  debug it , after jl it jump right to `exit:`
but the following code works fine

```
MOV AL, 88
   CMP AL, 24
   JL  exit
label:
   mov al,4h
exit:
   RET
```

why this is happening ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JL uses a *signed* condition. From a signed viewpoint, 88h is a negative number. If you want 24h to be treated as less than 88h, you have a couple of choices -- the most obvious would be to use an unsigned condition, which would mean using `jb` instead of `jl`.